# Rendering External Markup to page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Using VS2013, is there a way to render markup stored in a file to another page?

For instance:
If I store some basic markup in newFile.html,  is there a way to display that from another .aspx file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small javascript function that you pass the URL and the ID of the container, and load it using the .load() function.

```
        function loadPage(ID, URL) {

            $('#'+ ID).load(URL);
        }
```